# ArcGIS JS API Search source searchFields - multiple fields not working

Tags: javascript, api, url-encoding, esri, arcgis-js-api

My application is not able to search in two (or more) fileds. The same problem is in a sample application by ESRI.

ESRI app sample: http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=search_customized

On line 130, this is **OK**: `searchFields: ["Country"],`

this is **OK**, too: `searchFields: ["Rating"],`

but, this is **wrong**: `searchFields: ["Country", "Rating"],`

The documentation says, that `searchFields` is an array of fields to search in (see https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/search-amd.html#sources)

Why not working, what is wrong?

Comment: I have found, that the problem might be in URL encoding of the search request query part: `where=UPPER(Country) LIKE '%Spain%' or UPPER(Rating) LIKE '%Spain%'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I verified the link it is happening because of field data type; If you will open the sample layer REST URL you will see that "County" has string data type but "Rating" has integer data type.

**Layer's screen shot:**

[image]

It not like it doesn't supports combination; its supports such combinations just you need to take care while you pass value in text box that should be integer. because for string it uses "like" and for integer it uses "=" operator.

Hope this will help you :)